# Memcached .Net client BufferedStream error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, memcached

I am *trying* to use Memcached.ClientLibrary. I was able to make it work and everything but after a few hits (even before I get to see a page for the first time), I get this weird error about which I couldn't find any info when searching for it.

Error message:

> Cannot write to a BufferedStream while the read buffer is not empty if the underlying stream is not seekable. Ensure that the stream underlying this BufferedStream can seek or avoid interleaving read and write operations on this BufferedStream.

Stack trace:

```
[NotSupportedException: Cannot write to a BufferedStream while the read buffer is not empty if the underlying stream is not seekable. Ensure that the stream underlying this BufferedStream can seek or avoid interleaving read and write operations on this BufferedStream.]
System.IO.BufferedStream.ClearReadBufferBeforeWrite() +10447571
System.IO.BufferedStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +163
Memcached.ClientLibrary.SockIO.Write(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in C:\devroot\memcacheddotnet\trunk\clientlib\src\clientlib\SockIO.cs:411
Memcached.ClientLibrary.SockIO.Write(Byte[] bytes) in C:\devroot\memcacheddotnet\trunk\clientlib\src\clientlib\SockIO.cs:391
Memcached.ClientLibrary.MemcachedClient.Set(String cmdname, String key, Object obj, DateTime expiry, Object hashCode, Boolean asString) in C:\devroot\memcacheddotnet\trunk\clientlib\src\clientlib\MemCachedClient.cs:766
Memcached.ClientLibrary.MemcachedClient.Set(String key, Object value, DateTime expiry) in C:\devroot\memcacheddotnet\trunk\clientlib\src\clientlib\MemCachedClient.cs:465
Yuusoft.Julian.Server.Models.Utils.Caching.CacheWrapper.Add(CacheKey key, T o, CacheDependency dependencies, Nullable`1 expirationTime, CacheItemRemovedCallback callBack)
```

My code to initialize (static constructor):

```
        SockIOPool pool = SockIOPool.GetInstance();
        pool.SetServers(CacheWrapper.Servers);

        pool.InitConnections = 3;
        pool.MinConnections = 1;
        pool.MaxConnections = 50;

        pool.SocketConnectTimeout = 1000;
        pool.SocketTimeout = 3000;

        pool.MaintenanceSleep = 30;
        pool.Failover = true;

        pool.Nagle = false;
        pool.Initialize();
```

// Code to set (the second is the one erroing - but not at the first hit?!)

```
        MemcachedClient mc = new MemcachedClient();
        mc.Set(key, o, expirationTime.Value);
```

// Code to get

```
        MemcachedClient mc = new MemcachedClient();
        object o = mc.Get(key);
```

Comment: @DarthVader, published my code. Do you have any ideas? Something that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: @FabioMilheiro Please post your solution if this issue is resolved

Comment: @AbdulRaufMujahid, apologiesthis was an old experiment that I ended up not finishing. Good luck

Comment: In my case, I addition to the above mentioned exception. Following 2 exceptions were also present in my memcached logs (`Error storing data in cache for key:` and `Exception thrown while trying to get object from cache for key:`)
I was able to resolve all these 3 exceptions by ensuring that memcached key doesn't contain any whitespace.

Comment: @AbdulRaufMujahid, thanks for sharing. If you post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to this exception, following two exceptions were also present in my memcached **log4net** logs of Memcached.ClientLibrary (`Error storing data in cache for key:<key with spaces>` and `Exception thrown while trying to get object from cache for key:<key with spaces>`) I was able to resolve all these 
three exceptions by ensuring that memcached key doesn't contain any whitespace.

**Reference:**https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/4WMcTbL8ZZY

**Memcached Version:** memcached-win32-1.4.4-14